# Binding List of user controls to flipview?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I am planning to implement horizontal list of user controls, which i want to add it to the flip view during runtime, I tried the following code:

```
<FlipView Grid.Row="2" Name="SlideFlipView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind SlideViews}"
              SelectionChanged="SlideFlipView_SelectionChanged"
              Background="AliceBlue">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame Name="MenuDetailFrame" SourcePageType="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Class looks like the following code:

```
 public sealed partial class MenuDetailPage : Page
 {
    private List<object> SlideViews;

    public MenuDetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        LoadInitials();
    }

    private void LoadInitials()
    {
        SlideViews = new List<object>
        {
            typeof(TopImageBottomTextControl),
            typeof(TopTextBottomImageControl)
        };
    }
 }
```

but the user control doesn't appear in the flip when I run the program. Let me know if I am missing something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code without datatemplate worked for me:

```
<FlipView Grid.Row="2" 
          Name="SlideFlipView" 
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind SlideViews}"
          SelectionChanged="SlideFlipView_SelectionChanged"
          Background="AliceBlue">
</FlipView>
```

initialization of slideviews object in Class looks like

```
private void LoadInitials()
{
  SlideViews = new List<object>
  {
    new UserControl1(),
    new UserControl2()
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the ["Frame Class"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_SourcePageType):

> SourcePageType can be set in XAML, using string-to-type conversion that's interpreted using XAML namespace mappings, but that's rarely done. It's a better practice to have code at the app level that tracks activation and whether a suspended app is resuming, which then uses Frame.Navigate to set the current page.

For your requirement, you could bind the user control object to the `Content` of Frame.

```
private void LoadInitials()
{
    SlideViews = new List<object>
 {
    new TopImageBottomTextControl(),
    new TopImageBottomTextControl()
 };
}
```

**Usage**

```
<FlipView Name="SlideFlipView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind SlideViews}"
          SelectionChanged="SlideFlipView_SelectionChanged"
          Background="AliceBlue">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Name="MenuDetailFram"  Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Comment: Why does it need to  DataTemplate at all? Lists can render UI controls without using DataTemplate.

Comment: `DataTemplate` describes the visual structure of a data object. Use data binding for specific elements in the template that display the data values. For more you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate).

Comment: Flipview without datatemplate works for me. have posted the answer.